# CSS3 animation to fade out an image and fade in another image

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

At the moment I have a table within a div, the table has 2 rows the top row with 3 columns and the bottom row with 2 columns. The reason I am using tables is because I do not know how to set up the divs in this arrangement.

What I need to do is using CSS3 animation if possible, make the image within each cell fade out with a new image fading in on hover, but also to stay like it. I have got this far ok, however I want the image to change back to the original image if the user hovers over another image within a cell on the table.

Could somebody please show me how to do this? My code is also below.

**html**:

```
<div id="table">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="#b15ce2"><img src="transparentimage1.jpg" width="390" height="390" /></td>
  <td bgcolor="#70f940"><img src="transparentimage2.jpg" width="390" height="390" />&nbsp;</td>
  <td bgcolor="#4040f9"><img src="transparentimage3.jpg" width="390" height="390" />&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="#9933CC"><img src="transparentimage4.jpg" width="390" height="390" />&nbsp;</td>
  <td bgcolor="#33FF99" colspan="2"><img src="transparentimage5.jpg" width="390" height="390" />      </td>
</tr>
```

**css** :

```
#table {    
   position: absolute;
   width: 90%;
   height: 700px;
   left: 5%;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   border-radius: 20px;
   border: 8px solid #666666;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a bare basics example of how to do this!

## Step 1

Add classes to your images to specify which image ought to be immediately apparent, and which one ought to appear on hover. I'll use "img1" and "img2" - img1 is initially visible.

HTML:

```
<div class="hover-img">
    <img src="kjdflkjsdf.jpg" class="img1"/>
    <img src="lkgflsjgkl.jpg" class="img2"/>
</div>
```

## Step 2

Style the images to be absolute - this allows them to lie on top of each other, which is what we want since we want them to both appear in the same location. In order for absolute elements to render appropriately, their parent must have `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed` positioning. We'll go with `relative`.

CSS:

```
.hover-img {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px; height: 500px;
}
.hover-img > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%; /* Assuming that both images have the same dimensions - in thise case, 500x500 */
}
```

## Step 3

Style the 2nd image so that it is normally completely transparent (opacity: 0), and becomes fully opaque when the mouse hovers:

CSS:

```
.hover-img > .img2 {
    opacity: 0;
}
.hover-img:hover > .img2 {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

## Step 4

Cause the opacity attribute to transition instead of instantly change:

CSS:

```
.hover-img > .img2 {
    opacity: 0; /* This comes from step 3 */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

And there you have it!

(Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4p6Lk/)

Comment: would this be possible to switch from image to text content?

Comment: you'd probably need to use jquery to switch this to text content on hover

Comment: I don't think so! You can replace the img tag with anything else, as long as you keep the "img1" and "img2" classes. You could do span or p or div tag with text or any other content in it, and the fade should still work! :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use tables, they're very outdated. Look in to using floats and displaying divs using 'inline-block'.

It's possible to fade from one image to another using CSS

Create a div with a unique class/id:

`<div class="image"></div>`

target that div in CSS and add a background image (you will need to add positioning and size to this styling which I've skipped for this example). For the fading effect you need to add in the transition attribute and set transition style (i.e. ease-out, linear etc) and time (0.5s = 0.5 seconds).

`.image{background: url(../img/photo.jpg); -webkit-transition: ease-out 0.5s; transition: ease-out 0.5s;}`

Then add a different background image for your div when hovering

`.image:hover{background: url(../img/hoverphoto.jpg)}`

This is a simple solution, for more in-depth animations look in to CSS keyframe animations and jQuery onhover animation

Answer (score 0):

Much along the lines of Alan Sutherland, but with a full list of browser specific transition declarations...

```
#table td {
background: url('/path/to/some/image.png');
        transition: 0.25s;
     -o-transition: 0.25s;
    -ms-transition: 0.25s;
   -moz-transition: 0.25s;
-webkit-transition: 0.25s;
}
#table td:hover {
    background: url('/path/to/some/different-image.png');
}
```

This will affect every table cell within the element that has an id of table. All you're really needing to do is set a bg image for any cells you want, then use :hover psuedo-class to set a new BG image.

http://www.css3.info/preview/css3-transitions/ and specifically http://davidwalsh.name/background-animation-css (for backgrounds) might help you out a bit more.